# Returning CGPoint from a Method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface BBUtils : NSObject
{

}


-(CGPoint ) randomPoints;

@end
```

For some reason it complains on the randomPoints method saying Expected a Type? Why?

Comment: What's the implementation?

Comment: No implementation it complains in the interface (header) file.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code *per se*. Try selecting `CGPoint`, right-clicking, and choosing "Jump to Definition" - you should end up in `CGGeometry.h`. If you hit a different definition that is your problem. If you don't try cleaning out the project, or deleting the project and creating a new one. HTH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could happen if [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html) is not available. Then you'll need to link it explicitly:

[image]

Comment: Weird! I am using it on Xcode 6.1 with iOS SDK 8.1 and it complains about CGPoint. It does not even recognize CGPoint structure.

Comment: No problem here, tested with targeting both OSX 10.10 and iOS 8.1. Are you sure your project didn't somehow remove CoreGraphics from it's template?

Comment: CoreGraphics was the issue! Thanks a lot! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Add proper import in your header to expose structs declared by CoreGraphics:

`#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>`

Comment: @ClausJørgensen You are wrong. `Foundation` does not include any of `CoreGraphics` types such as `CGSize`. You need to explicitly include `CoreGraphics.h`. On the other side UIKit does include `CoreGraphics.h`. Don't believe me? Inspect the framework headers or make a sample class and do not use `.pch` because it used to include `UIKit` before Xcode 6. Your answer is incomplete and OP got away with it because he probably had UIKit around or any other framework that includes CoreGraphics.